# Select waveform on AKNodeOutputPlot (AudioKit)

Tags: swift, macos, audiokit

I gon a microfone recorder (AKNodeRecorder) with all appropriate setup and analyzer (AKNodeOutputPlot) thats show a waveform through recording and showing recorded file plot after record stoped. All works fine. The question is how i can select different pieces of audio on the plot, or set markers in the touched points for further editing?

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box.  This is app level functionality you'll have to add.